# C# Winform textbox validating broke cancel button

Tags: c#, winforms, validation, event-handling, visual-studio-2013

I am making a `winform` application in `C#` with `visual studio 2013`. On my form I have a few `text-boxes` and a couple `buttons`.

More specifically I have a `cancelButton` that when click will close the application, which is handled with this event here.

```
private void cancelButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //close the application
    Application.Exit();
}
```

I have a `TextBox_Validated` event that looks something like this

```
private void aTextBox_Validated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int matchIntPosition;
    string someString = aTextBox.Text.ToUpper();

    //check a string array to see if the value entered exsists
    matchIntPosition= Array.IndexOf(someStringArray, someString);
    if (matchIntPosition > -1)
    {
        string someString = someStringArray[matchIntPosition];
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("This value does not exist, Please try again.");
        aTextBox.Focus();
    }
}
```

Now I am forcing the user to make sure that this field is properly filled out before continuing on my form(This is the first textbox on my form).

Here is where my issue is, When I click my cancelButton, it just hits the `else` within my `aTextBox_Validation` event. Forcing me to type in a proper value before I can hit the cancel button.

I have done a bit of google-ing to try and figure out how I can fix it. Some of the things that I have tried are:

`cancelButton.CausesValidation = false;` within my `cancelButton_Click` event, did not work.

Tried to set a `bool` flag to do almost the same thing as ^, that did not seem to work either.

Any idea's or a push to the right place?

Comment: Where is declared someStringArray variable? Does it contains the someString variable value?

Comment: I would try to validate all textboxes on the submit button click.  That's very normal form behavior.  It would fix your issue, and prevent end customers from getting frustrated that you keep moving the focus around on them.

Comment: @yosoy the array is at class level, you missed the point of my question.

Comment: Setting `cancelButton.CausesValidation = false;` in the click event is too late.  Set that value in the designer.

Comment: @jonesy I have moved all the validation to a OK button(submit). However, when I hit OK my error message will display, but then the rest of my process's than begin, with errors of course.

Comment: try to use `Validating` event instead of `Validated`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do your validation on the "Submit" button then.  The problem is, the `Validated` event always fires when you leave the text field, so this will happen even when you go to click the "Cancel" button.

Comment: I've moved everything into my OK button (or submit). However when the textbox value is invalid, my error message will display but then the rest of my program continues, I believe ill have to mix up some of my logic with my `if/else` and I should get it to work how I would like. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set:

AutoValidate=EnableAllowFocusChange

On the containing form.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the textbox validation running when the textbox loses focus then hitting the cancel button will cause the textbox to lose focus and thus validate before closing.